# how to resolve version mismatch issue when we deploy server side rendering (e.g. nuxt ssr) on firebase function + firebase hosting w/ cache

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting

When we deploy a new version, the firebase cloud function & firebase hosting would be deployed at different time.

If a user visits the page in between, the firebase hosting could cache a different version from the cloud function's and persist the issue until the (CDN) cache expires.

| Hosting | Function |
| --- | --- |
| New version deployed |  |
| New Visit, no cache, so fetch from cloud function |  |
|  | returns older version !!!! |
|  | new version deployed |

How do we design the deployment to resolve the issue?

Comment: You can't chain them? Wait for the build and function to be done in a sequential way before releasing to production?

Comment: they are 2 different firebase commands:

firebase deploy --only "functions:$1" 

firebase deploy --only hosting:website

and there will always be a time span that the versions are different can cause problems for the visitors.

Comment: There is probably a way to either chain them or wait for both to finish. This could not be possible otherwise.

Comment: That would be a clean solution. Otherwise, we have to keep both versions and  decide on-the-fly the right version based on the header / environment etc.